# Error: Element tbody not allowed as child of element table in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html

I have the following HTML code and the following error happens on the `<tbody>` line:

```
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Werewolves</td>
                        <td>100 sighting</td
                        <td>12 sightings</td>
                        <td>210 people were attacked</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Vampires</td>
                        <td>5,000 vampires live in the U.S., drink donors' blood</td>
                        <td>206 sightings</td>
                        <td>Unknown</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Demons</td>
                        <td>9,000 sightings</td>
                        <td>Unknown</td>
                        <td>family of 12 saw demons.</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Dragons</td>
                        <td>3 Sightings</td>
                        <td>Unknown</td>
                        <td>Unknown</td>

                    </td>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Aliens</td>
                        <td>43 Sightings of UFO's</td>
                        <td>55 Sightings of UFO's</td>
                        <td>7 sightings</td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </aside>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <p>Copywrite_20180 Home Of The Supernatural</p>
    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Error: Element tbody not allowed as child of element table in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Instead, paste it into your question and format it as code. You should also give more information about what you're code is supposed to do.

Comment: im having issues with the tbody

Comment: Make sure all tags in your page are closed and this page is valid html.

Comment: its valid but the tbody does not work

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's legal to have a **tfoot** section prior to the **tbody** (there should also be no **tr** tags prior to the **tbody**).

See: [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-tbody-element)